# Unable to automatically step into the server. The remote procedure could not be debugged. Can't step into the web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, debugging, remote-debugging

I know this has been asked million of times, but i can't find the answer i'm looking for.

I have to take over a .NET 2.0 WinForms application inside my company. There's a solution file that I took from Source Safe, in which there's this application as well as Web Service. However, even though both in same solution, the WS with enabled debugging, I can't step into the Web Service. Any suggestions on what I could do? I tried some changes to the pool in the IIS, I tried rebuilding both the app and the WS, I tried everything i've ever done, and it's not working.

I also develop/maintain another app, web app in .NET 2.0, that uses WS from different solution, and once both started, i can step into the WS with no problems at all. But the first one, the WinForms one, is making my life very hard.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the ASMX and WinForms run under the context of 2 different applications. A WinForms App makes a web service request. This is received by a remote application which just happens to be as part of the same solution.

Here are 2 options to debug them simultaneously:

**Option #1**

1. With the solution containing the Web Service Project & WinForms, start up the Web Services Project. The ASMX page will come up. Note the Uri.
2. Now right click on the WinForms project, Debug -> New Instance and load up the Winforms Form. Ensure that the Service Uri is same as #1.
3. Put breakpoints on both the source code files and they should be hit.

**Option #2**

1. The Project can be contained in separate solutions or the same one.
2. Start the web service project. The asmx page will come up. Note the Uri.
3. 'Debug => Attach To Process' and attach to the IExplore/w3wp process.
4. Run the Winforms Project. Ensure that the Service Uri is same as #1.
5. Put breakpoints on both the source code files and they should be hit.

Comment: strange enough, i can't even browse the WS. When I've set it up as startup project, and when tried to start it in debug mode it said "Unable to start debugging on the Web Server". To me it seems like some server configuration is bad, the IIS maybe or something else. Any other idea?